# Extract a range of rows from CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm very new to PHP and have been experimenting with combining with css to turn a CSV file into a table on my site. I wondered if you could select to show just a range of rows from a CSV file, e.g. rows 5 to 20, and found the code below to show certain columns.

Is there a simple way to switch this to show selected rows instead?

```
<?php
 $row = 1;
 if (($handle = fopen("donors.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {

        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }
        if ($row == 1) {

             echo '<td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(111,180,224); border-left: 1px solid rgb(111,180,224); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(111,180,224);"  align="left" bgcolor="#0066cc" height="36" valign="middle" ><b><font color="#ffffff" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$value.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></td>';
        }else{


            echo '<td style=" border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(111,180,224);" sdval="9" sdnum="1040;" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="25"  valign="middle"><font color="#000000" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$value.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>';
        }
    }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $row++;
   }

  echo '</tbody></table>';
echo '</center>';   
    fclose($handle);
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure to undestand what you want to display.

But on the test website i added a table which diplay a range of lines.

Here is the code of this table:

```
echo "<meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"/>
      <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"test.css\">";
$file = '/var/www/test/test.csv'; 
echo "<h1><b>Lines X to Y</b></h1>";
echo "<table>";                     //create the html table
$x=2;       //define the first line to display
$y=4;       //define the last line to display
$line_counter=0;
foreach ($lines as $line) {         //loop to fill your table with csv data
  if($x<=$line_counter && $line_counter<=$y)
  {
    $expl = explode(",", $line);      //explode each line on "," to create the rows
    echo "<tr>";                      //create each line of your table
    $c=0;
    while ($c<=26) {                  //loop to extract rows 5 to 20
      if(($c % 2) == 1){              //odd  rows
        echo "<td class=\"odd\">".$expl[$c]."</td>";
      }
      elseif(($c == 0)){
        echo "<td class=\"even\">".$expl[$c]."</td>";
      }
      else{
        echo "<td class=\"even\">".$expl[$c]."</td>";    //even rows
      }
      $c++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $x++;
  }
  $line_counter++;
}
echo "</table>";

echo "<h1><b>content of the file</b></h1>";
foreach ($lines as $line) {         //loop to fill your table with csv data
  echo "$line<br/>" ;   
}
```

The CSS is always in a separate file, and is the same as my first answer.

Comment: **[HERE](http://94.23.110.242/test/test.php)** is a link to the test website. Because i can't post an IP link is the answer ...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply - this works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Actually, there is one problem with this - it doesn't recognise quote marks in CSV files i.e. it shows them instead of seeing them as tags around entries. Is there a way of getting the fgetcsv command into the code to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

**Select a range of rows:**

i adapted this code from an old project, but it should work.

```
<?php 
echo "<meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"/>
      <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"test.css\">";
$file = '/volume1/web/Print data.csv';   
$lines = file($file);
if (file_exists($file)){
  //echo "$file exists<br/>"; 
  echo "<table>";                      //create the html table
  foreach ($lines as $line) {         //loop to fill your table with csv data
    $expl = explode(",", $line);      //explode each line on "," to create the rows
    echo "<tr>";                      //create each line of your table
    $c=5;
    while ($c<=20) {                  //loop to extract rows 5 to 20
      if(($c % 2) == 1){              //odd  rows
      echo "<td class=\"odd\">".$expl[$c]."</td>";
      }
      else{
        echo "<td class=\"even\">".$expl[$c]."</td>";    //even rows
      }
      $c++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
else{
  echo "file is not here: $file";
}
?>
```

**For the css:**

you should use an external `.css`file with this code

```
.odd {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(111, 180, 224);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(111, 180, 224);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(111, 180, 224);
    background:#0066cc;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
}
.even {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(111, 180, 224);
    background: #ffffff;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

To check this css you can see this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f_vincent/pyJ6P/)**

I hope it will help you.

**Edit**

Fixed some missing `;`. Added an picture of the result

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried your suggestion, but I'm getting an error: 
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting ',' or ';' in 'path to my php file' on line 15". Any ideas?

Comment: Nearly, but not quite. I no longer get the original error, but all I get now is a tiny table with no data in it? I'm fairly certain my CSV file is being found, and have tried several things with no success?

Comment: i can't tell you what is going wrong. Can you provide the code you are using( if you made some change). And at least one line of your csv file,in order to check what is going on.

Comment: you get a tiny table without data. Can you check if the separator is really a `,`. if not you must change it in the line `$expl = explode(",", $line);`

Comment: I've literally dropped the suggested code into a php file and css file respectively. I changed the csv path to point to my csv file:<br/><br/> 

$file = 'CSV/test.csv';<br/><br/>

My csv file is also just a test file, that looks like this:<br/><br/>

aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,eeee<br/>
1111,2222,3333,4444,5555<br/>
1112,2223,3334,4445,5556<br/>
1113,2224,3335,4446,5557<br/><br/>

Here is the result:[link](http://www.magicproductions.org.uk/sfp/phptest_specificrowsx.php)

Comment: Apologies for the messy looking reply above - not sure how to display the information properly in the comments box. The <br/> aren't actually in the csv file, I was simply trying to but a line breaks in my comment!

Comment: your table is empty because something is wrong somewhere...
Are you sure :

   - your table have the correct numbers of rows, at least 20.

   - the separator is a `,`.

I upload my code [HERE](http://94.23.110.242/test/test.php) you can check.
You can find all the files i used [HERE](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2thX_89haiTLU9PVFFfZUltemM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've found the problem - our definition of a row. What you've called a row I would call a column. My CSV file only had 4 fields of data from left to right, so there was no information in the 5-20th fields. Once I populated those, it all works fine! However, it's filtering the data the other way that I'm trying to achieve, from top to bottom. So, in your 'Complete Table' example, is it possible to just show the information from a-z and 0-25? Would you call these columns?

Answer (score 0):

1) Fetch your CSV file to an array with the below function (source:  [jaywilliams @ GIST](https://gist.github.com/jaywilliams/385876))

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;

$header = NULL;
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
return $data;
}
```

2) Iterate over the desired range of rows

```
$data = csv_to_array($file,$delimiter); 

echo "your table header stuff"; //<table> ... 

//first row numbered as 1 
$from_row = 2; //second
$to_row = 50;

//first row numbered as 0 
for($i = from_row-1; $i< $to_row-1; $i++) 
{
   echo "<tr>"; //start row

   //now, every row of the CSV file is an array and consists of fileds=>values
   //so now you are dealing with columns   

   foreach($data[$i] as $key=>$value
   {
          echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"; 
   }
    echo "</tr>"; //end row
}

echo "your table footer stuff"; //</table> ...
```

From here, I guess you can do whatever your want, using CSS to style the tables. What is important, if you want the table header, you can feed the function with a CSV file with col names saved in first row.